# Decode(), len(), Scandinavian Iso String is printed correctly but length is wrong

Tags: python, string, decode, encode, string-length

svenskaOrd is a list of Swedish words.
Id like to print the length of the word in letters, and the word with correct formatting, only if 4 or above in length.
Only formatting is correct.

```
swedishWords = open("svenskaOrd.txt","r")

for line in swedishWords:
    if(len(line.decode("iso8859_10")) >= 4):
        print(len(line.decode("iso8859_10")))
        print(line.decode("iso8859_10"))
```

**Output:**

....

18
öroninflammation

5
ört

10
örtagård

....

Comment: You are including the linebreaks and possibly other whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

By default `open` opens file in text mode. This decodes raw bytes into text. You shouldn't need to open a file in text mode and then decode the text gain. It doesn't make sense. Python 3 won't even let you do this and would report an error (because `str` has no `decode` method).

If you know your text file has a given encoding then you should give that to `open`

```
swedishWords = open("svenskaOrd.txt", "r", encoding="iso8859_10")

for line in swedishWords:
    if(len(line) >= 4):
        print(len(line))
        print(line)
```

If you really want to operate on raw bytes then open the file in raw mode and decode each line.

```
swedishBytes = open("svenskaOrd.txt", "rb")
```